# UICollectionViewCell Reuse with Asynchronous Image Loading wrong image

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, uicollectionview

I am creating a UICollectionView that initially downloads images from an AWSS3 bucket, then caches the images for later access. The problem is that since the download takes some time, when the user scrolls the UICollectionView more downloads are queued up. The first batch of downloads finishes and loads into the newly visible cells, then the second batch of downloads finishes and replaces the same cells.

This results in images appearing in cells they should not. I have attempted the solutions from similar posts but have not found one works.

Here is a simplified version of what I have tried

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    var cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("imageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GroupImageCell

    cell.imageView.image = nil

    getPhotoForCell(cell, indexPath)
}

func getPhotoForCell(cell: GroupImageCell, idx: NSIndexPath)
{
    #use AWSS3downloadrequest
    #once results are in
    if (task.result != nil) {
        #get body of result, then url, then data
        let data = NSData(data: task.result.body as! NSURL)

        let image = UIImage(data: data)
        if (collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(idx) != nil)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                cell.imageView.image = image
            })
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this issue by storing the images in your model object that is used for each cell. Meaning, instead of

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                cell.imageView.image = image
            })
```

Do something like this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                items[indexPath.row].image = image
            })
```

This way you will guarantee to render the correct image when you call from your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    var cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("imageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GroupImageCell

    cell.imageView.image = items[indexPath.row].image
}
```